# Loop random words words using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I found this code here on Stackoverflow which displays random words onpage load and shows a new one when one reloads page. Being new to Javascript, i do not know how to make it loop between the words once page loads. That is displaying a new word from the list after every one second.

The Code is

```js
var things = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissor'];
var thing = things[Math.floor(Math.random()*things.length)];
alert('The computer chose:' + thing);
```

EDIT: I would like to be priting the result on the page and not using alert.

Comment: "make it loop" this is exactly the term you should be searching for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum [`setInterval`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/setInterval) is more relevant here.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _“loop between the words”_? Can you [edit] your question and show some example output? Other than that, see [Call a Javascript function every 5 seconds continuously](/q/7188145/4642212) and [Prevent alert() from halting the execution of JavaScript](/q/33203157/4642212).

Comment: But you don't want to repeatedly "loop and alert" with `setInterval` otherwise you'll be there all day closing down alerts.

Comment: @Andy i won't be using the alert, i will rather be printing on the page

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that using that code you might get 20 "paper" in a row because of how the random number is generated.

Comment: @Andy what would be  the best way to fix that?

Comment: @StevenHelson  Just create an inner loop, and keep calling Random() until your new value is different to your last value (create a second variable to hold that value.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you only have a small set of items you want to loop over, and are trying to prevent the same "random" item from being written lots of times in a row, you'll have to implement some sort of "remembering" system. Here I make a copy of the array and [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) words from it, and then reset it once it's empty.

I've also used [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#working_with_asynchronous_functions) in this example. (Personal preference.) You'll still occasionally get the same word come up twice in a row as the array resets. If you wanted no repeated words you can build that check into the function, but I think that defeats the whole purpose of "rock, paper, scissors" - sometimes you *want* to play "paper" 20 times in a row :)

```js
const arr = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissor'];
const el = document.querySelector('#demo');

// `log` accepts and array of words, and an element
function log(arr, el) {

  // Makes a copy of that array
  let copy = [...arr];

  // Main loop that `setTimeout` calls over and over...
  function loop() {

    // Get the random number
    const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);

    // Get a word by `splicing` it out of the array copy
    const word = copy.splice(rnd, 1);

    // Updated the element text content
    el.textContent = `The computer chose: ${word}`;

    // If there are no words left in the copy, reset it
    if (!copy.length) copy = [...arr];

    // Call `loop` again
    setTimeout(loop, 1000);
  
  }

  // Call `loop`
  loop();

}

log(arr, el);
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Wanted to ask if it is possible to put the result in a variable rather that logging into console?

Comment: You want to log the result as textContent of an element?

Comment: Yes Exactly. I want to log the result as textContent of an element.

Comment: Answer updated! @StevenHelson. Just cache the element, and pass it in as an argument. That way you're not hitting the DOM on every iteration which is better for performance.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)

```js
const things = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissor'];

setInterval(function() {
   const thing = things[Math.floor(Math.random()*things.length)];
   console.log('The computer chose : ' + thing);
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer to your question requires knowledge of two things.
**setInterval** and **document query selectors**. To answer you in the most simple way possible I have divided solution to HTML and JS codes. In the HTML section you can see the DOM Element "p". It has ID called "random-thing". In CSS We refer to it, as #random-thing.

JavaScript code selects this element (**Warning, it can be null, that's why we want to check whether it exists.**). Then we can change element's property called innerText. You could also change it using **innerHTML**, but because we only want to change the text content, let's use the innerText property.

```js
  const randomThingDomEl = document.getElementById("random-thing");
  const things = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissor'];
  const getRandomThing = () => things[Math.floor(Math.random()*things.length)];

  setInterval(() => {
   if (randomThingDomEl) {
    randomThingDomEl.innerText = getRandomThing();
   }
  }, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="random-thing" />
```

Comment: Console generates the ReferenceError: randomThingDomEL is not defined

Comment: Excuse me for my typo, try to run it again :)

Comment: @MaciejGórski you can create a working snippet for this if you edit your question and use the `[<>]` option in the toolbar.

Comment: Wow! Smarter every day :) Thanks.